# Firefox won't display an image!

Tags: html, css, firefox

This is very interesting to me...  This image displays perfectly well in Safari, but not at all in Firefox! Here's the relevant code:

```
<div id="ad">
    <p>Advertisment</p>
    <img src="/ADS/fakead1.gif" />
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
#ad{color: #666;}
#ad p{
    font-size: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#ad img{
    width: 9em;
    padding: .5em;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Why would this code cause Firefox to simply *ignore* the image?  (Again, it works perfectly fine with Safari.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow, I'm not so smart...

AdBlock Plus is smarter that I would have thought!  I'll need to change the div name to something less obvious than "ad" (!)

I should have known.

A word to the wise: if you want your ad to get through, name the div in klingon.

Comment: I think Firefox knows Klingon too ;)

Comment: Is nobody going to comment on the hypocrisy of using AdBlock Plus, and then embedding ads on your own website, and further obfuscating the fact they are ads specifically to defeat AdBlock plus???  Why not use the obvious and allow users of AdBlock to block them?

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, @SoftwareMonkey, this was just for practice.  It never went live.  If I had been making a public website, I would at least have had the decency to not to circumvent ad blockers!

Answer (score 2):

it works for me here. its just your adblock i would say